# desktop sharing with android phone using ssh

Tags: java, android

This is what i want to do in java

1. Connect my android phone to an ubuntu server using ssh
2. Share(control) my desktop's server from my phone

I have done the first part successfully but not able to do the second part. I don't want to do this with the apps already available. I have no idea where to start from. Is there any library to share desktop in java? Or can i send stream of images from server to do the same?

Any help is appreciated.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Most android vnc viewers will work. I've used PocketCloud Remote RDP / VNC.

Also on the google play store X server is an option

Answer (score 0):

You can run graphical applications on your desktop and view them on your phone in one of two ways:

- Run an X server on your phone, such as [the Darkside server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.XServer). This may be best if you want to run individual applications on your desktop and display them on your phone.
- Use [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) to share your entire desktop onto your phone. This doesn't require SSH (the VNC protocol runs over a network connection anyway), but you can tunnel it through SSH for security and compression. This may be best if you want access to your existing logged-in desktop; it's usually easy to share it from the major desktop environments.